# Erro no metodo Get da biblioteca Requests em Python

Tags: python, http-request, biblioteca, python-requests

Estou tentando aprender a usar a biblioteca Requests em python, mas tem um erro que não sei resolver, em vários tutoriais cria-se a variavel `r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')` mas meu VSCode apresenta um erro => Module 'requests' has no 'get' member. Get não é um método de re[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]quests?

Comment: Qual versão do python esta usando amigo? E se vc tenta rodar esse mesmo comando pela linha de comando, sem ser pelo VSCODE, da erro?

Comment: to usando o python 3.7.4 e no Idle ele executa normalmente, eu so to confuso pq o VSCode não ta aceitando o metodo.

Comment: Que estranho, estou usando a versão Python 3.6.8 e VSCODE 1.38.0 e não consigo reproduzir esse erro que você mostrou, no meu é reconhecido normalmente. Esta usando alguma extenção para python no vscode?

Comment: To usando a extensão da microsoft python, vou tentar atualizar o VScode pra ver se consigo resolver isso.

Comment: Não é problema no VS Code, mas sim no seu arquivo. Você nomeou o arquivo como `requests.py`, então quando faz `import requests` você está importando o próprio arquivo nele mesmo ao invés de importar a biblioteca. Como seu arquivo não possui um `get` definido dá o erro. Nunca nomeia seus arquivos com nomes dos módulos do Python.

Comment: Anderson, tenho um arquivo que se chama scan_dns_diretorios.py e ele usa o requests, e apresenta o mesmo erro, acredito que não seja isso, apesar de ser uma má pratica de programação, mas vou mudar o nome do arquivo kkk.

Comment: Se o arquivo está no mesmo diretório possui exatamente o mesmo problema, importando o seu arquivo requests.py ao invés da biblioteca. Na resolução de nomes dos módulos o Python sempre priorizará módulos locais antes de buscar por globais.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que seu arquivo está nomeado como **requests.py**. O erro está sendo gerado porque você não está importando a biblioteca `requests` e sim o seu módulo que não possui a função `get`. Esse erro será apresentado não só para este módulo como para outros que irão importar o seu **requests.py**.

Renomeie ele para outro nome e teste novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Como o amigo disse ali encima mesmo, seu arquivo está nomeado de **requests.py**. O mesmo ocorreria se você criasse um arquivo chamado **selenium.py** tentando usar o modulo selenium-webdriver.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).